# C to C++ How do I make h/w initialization look neat?

Tags: c, firmware, c++

Doing an experimental conversion of some firmware from C to C++ to try and get a better structure in it, since the C code "evolved" in line with experiments across a 2 year period.

The question is about how I package/wrap the large number of lines of MCU setup that I have, generally of the form

> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin =  GPIO_Pin_9;

Where the struct and definitions above are part of the MCU library (which I don't want to touch)

Or do I just drop then into a "floating" function called init()?

Comment: H/W initialization code is almost always ugly.  Many times, the order is important, and timing can even become involved.  An init function or module is often used to wrap it up out of both sight and harm's way.

Comment: This is a highly subjective matter, unless you can objectively define "neat".

Answer (score 2):

I more or less agree with Vicente that if you use objects, then the constructors of those objects are the places to do such hardware initialisation.

But I very much dislike names like "IOManager", because it doesn't convey what the thing does (managers generally don't do anything usefull, right?) and it probably bundles the actions in the wrong way, which gives rise to the classic comment from the C caps that they can't see what is done when an IOManager object is constructed. That isn't the fault of OO, it is the consequence of bad naming and/or partitioning. It is not initialization code that should be grouped thogether but the use of a peripheral (initialization and operational use).

Let's assume that you use an SPI bus, or an LCD, or an analog current sensor. IMO the object you initialize should be named after its use, hence (for instance) an HD44780 LCD that is used as logging output. The object creation should look something like

```
HD44780 logger( ... );
```

What is at the ... depends on how flexible the HD44780 object is. If the pins and the size (lines x columns) and other details are totaly fixed (could be the case for a project, but it is a bad idea for a (re-usable) library) this knowledge might be inside the HD44780 class. If not, pass this info as parameters. If you have the resources, pass objects that represent the pins. In that case the initialization of the pins is done in the pin constructors (maybe you want a port (= a bundle of pins) for the d4-d7).

```
gpio lcd_e( 12 );
...
HD44780( lcd_e, ... );
```

This puts pin initialization in the one place it realy should be: the pin library class.

If you can't afford the overhead of objects for pins, consider passing pin numbers, and have the HD44780 call the pin library to do the initialization. If you use macros or inline functions for accessing the pins this can be as efficient as using the pins directly (somewhat like the Arduino Wiring library).

An OO abstraction offers flexibility and reusability and good code structure (and it looks familiar to an OO programmer), but it doesn't come free: those objects take up RAM, and calling virtual functions takes time and blocks optimizations (but link-time optimization gets better and better at removing such overhead). Hence I prefer a static-class / template-based apparoach which avoids this overhead for compile-time known hierargies. This has a cost too: it looks a bit weird, even to seasoned C++ programmers. But is can be as efficient as dedicated C code. Check [Objects? No Thanks!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8sRQMx2qUw) for more explanation.

Odin Holmes advocates an approach that is even more radical, where each module specifies its initialization requirements, which are then (at compile time!) combined. Multiple writes to different bitfields of the same register are thus merged into one assignment.

Comment: I've written a C++ proof of concept blinker which - with optimizations in GCC - compiled to something similar to hand-crafted assembly. The question: how do you avoid code bloat in non-optimized builds with templates? (As used in debugging)

Comment: @JanDorniak I use classes to bundle (static) functions. The class is passed as template parameter. This allows inlining. The inked youtube gives more details.

Comment: I think I grasp the idea (wtithout the video) - something like Linux kernel-style drivers but instead of passing a struct with callback pointers you pass a class. Neat. Although to make it error out nicely there is *a lot* of SFINAE metaprogramming to do. Although thinking about my use case where I actually use function pointers on the MCU (STM32F4 with FreeRTOS) - this template solution would not work. Message routing where I actually need function pointers/virtual methods.

Comment: And yes, I program in both C and C++. C in Linux kernel and on MCUs, C++ in Linux user space.

Comment: There was quite some SFINAE in my first version. I am now working on a new version that uses concepts, which simplifies things a lot. For message routing between FSMs Odin Holmes has done some work. Nothing finished AFAIK, but at least a glimpse of how it can be done statically (without function pointers or virtuals).

Comment: well, in the MCU the module addresses are usually static. And business inertia is killer - I can't properly introduce CMake... Do you have an open source project I could look at/try to help?

Comment: My current effort is at github.com/wovo/hwcpp, but recently I started all over again from scratch. Major parts will have to wait untill P0732R2 (class types in non-type template parameters) is implemented. What I could use most is discussion!

Answer (score 2):

> GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;

This already looks quite horrible, which is probably the fault of the library.

More readable code would be `PORTX |= PORTX_PIN9;` or alternatively `PORTX |= 1u<<PORTX_PIN9;` - this code is universally understood by all programmers. Abstraction layers only add clutter.

You *can* add an abstraction layer for GPIO, in case GPIO on the specific part is non-trivial. Suppose you need to set up pin routining registers or similar. Or alternatively, you want GPIO access code to be portable across projects. In that case you can create HAL on top of the GPIO access.

So lets say we decide to create a HAL called `GPIO`. If we do it in a C ADT called `gpio.h`/`gpio.c` or in a C++ class called `class GPIO` doesn't matter. It would need to have functions such as `gpio_set` and `gpio_read` to set or read the status of the pin. Other features such as data direction registers, pull-registers and interrupts can be added.

This ADT/class needs to be a singleton and it should not need any private variables. Most likely all member functions are `static`.

The important thing is that this GPIO HAL knows how to set ***a pin***, but it does not know how to set ***the specific pin that does task X***. That part of application logic should be in other parts of the program.

Now the next problem with having a HAL like this is that GPIO data direction & pull registers need to be set as early on as possible, in order to get best EMI and ESD performance etc. This means those registers need to be set *long before* the "CRT" does the initialization of .bss/.data and calls C++ constructors of objects with static storage duration.

So using a C++ constructor to set these registers is a no-go, that's simply not professional, as it means that critical registers will be set far too late. (Or even worse, have the C++ GPIO object as some local variable with automatic storage.)

Rather, you need to integrate the GPIO setup in the "CRT" code somehow, or - since most "CRT" provided by compilers are crap - write it yourself.

See these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940277/584518) for how to setup a MCU in a professional application. C++ constructors are typically called after the .bss/.data part, which is why they are unsuitable to use for any form of fundamental hardware like GPIO or watchdog setup.

Comment: This looks like an STM32 HAL - likely the depreciated StdPerphLib. And setting a GPIO can involve up to three out of four total registers, most with two bits per pin. And yes - the libs (both of them) are horrible. Nice point is that all ports have exactly the same register structure so having port defined in the structure is unnecessary and even confusing.

Comment: Note that both register and bit definitions are provided as part of CMSIS and can be easily extracted from ST's HAL

Comment: @JanDorniak ST doesn't quite grasp the meaning of HAL. To them it is "hide away scary hardware-related code". Rather than the real meaning: provide a portable interface on top of drivers, so that application-layer code doesn't need to be rewritten when the code is ported. ST, being a MCU manufacturer, has of course no interest in providing easier portability away from their own MCUs to the competitors.

Comment: So ST make a "HAL" like `SetRegister59(baudrate)` which hides away `REGISTER59 = baudrate;`. Rather than a proper HAL which would say `spi_initialize(baudrate)`, with no care about register 59 happening to be ST:s internal name for the SPI baudrate register. And of course some MCU manufacturers won't even use the name SPI but call it some name of their own, like "magical serial bus", acting like it is something exclusive to their own MCU.

Comment: I know their code is... Bad (no swearing on SE :/ ). At first I was afraid to ignore it. Then circumstances forced me to use direct registers. Wrote my own drivers. Never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is using class constructors for setup. Say you have a class for IO management called IOManager. In IOManager.h:

```
class IOManager {
public:
    IOManager();
    // ... other relevant functions or variables ...
}
```

Then in IOManager.cpp:

```
#include "IOManager"
#include // the MCU includes

IOManager::IOManager() {
    // initialization code goes here, like the example:
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
}
```

Now, when you call the initilization of an instance of IOManager, its constructor code will be executed.

```
#include "IOManager"

int main() {
    IOManager myIOManager; // calling this will make the constructor be executed
    // ... rest of code using myIOManager ...
}
```

One can argue this approach kind of "hides" what the code is really doing, but it is an uncluttered way for specifying what is the initialization required for each different MCU module. In my opinion, this is also what a "constructor function" was meant to be used for in the MCU context.

Comment: This is bad OO design. GPIO should be handled by the class using the specific pin. You can add an abstraction layer (HAL) on top of the port access, but then that HAL needs to be called from every class in the program using I/O pins. You should not have some "manager" or "handler" knowing everything about all unrelated hardware in the system, and therefore doing magical things. This creates a tight coupling between the "manager" and every other unrelated hardware in the program. Rather you should have something like the function `SPI::send` in the `SPI class` calling `IO.set(Pin9);`.

Comment: This is probably the best and quickest approach to wrapping up existing initialization code rather than doing a total re-write.

Comment: @DirkBruere Note that adding some function/class "setup_all_hardware()" is just a way to move away hardware setup code from the application code - it is not proper OO design, and since it isn't, C++ provides no advantage here. If you don't use OO design, there is very little use for C++.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining why GPIO setup should not be placed in a C++ constructor.